# delete border around input field in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

I have next code:

```
<div class="form_field">
<input type="text" />
</div>
```

styles

```
.form_field { height:22px; border:1px solid #B7AB8C; background:#FFFFEA; padding:0 5px; line-height:22px; }
.form_field input[type="text"] { width:100%; border:none; border:0; border-color: transparent; margin:0; padding:0; height:22px; line-height:22px; }
```

In IE7 I can't remove the border around the input field.

What are the ideas?

---

The best decision for myself, I identified as set a class for field "input" as recommended "tylerdurden".

And I add next properties for this field as "background:transparent; vertical-align:top;".

But I could not override the property line-height for field "input".
What are the ideas? (:

Added: I removed the property "height" for container .form_field - helped to align text vertically.

Comment: If I had IE7 installed on one of my systems, I could test this...

Answer (score 4):

For IE7 you'll have to add a classname to the input element, or select it in a different way as IE<8 doesn't support attribute selectors.

But this css should work with the right selector:

```
.form_field input
{
  border:0
}
```

But please note that using `border-color: transparent;` with `border: none;` will impact the input’s box model by removing the border dimensions.
This will alter the input’s relationship, like vertical positioning, with surrounding elements.

Answer (score 3):

This is because the code below for input[type="text"] is not known in IE7 or below.

```
.form_field input[type="text"] { width:100%; border:none; border:0; border-color: transparent; margin:0; padding:0; height:22px; line-height:22px; }
```

Note: IE7 and IE8 support attribute selectors only if a !DOCTYPE is specified. Attribute selection is NOT supported in IE6 and lower.

You may want to add this to the top of your html.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need quotes around `"text"` in the CSS selector. Instead of all those `border` proerties, just do `border: 0;` on its own (or if you want to be thorough `border: 0px none transparent` but that's overkill)

Answer (score 0):

Give a class to text field ;

```
.form_field .textInput
{
    border:none;
}
```

Then in your html;

```
<div class="form_field">
    <input type="text" class="textInput" />
</div>
```

Comment: IE7 actually treats border: none; and border: 0; differently! 0 is the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style type="text/css">
.form_field input{
  filter:chroma(color=#000000);
  border:none;
}
</style>
<![endif]-->
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems IE7 doesn't want the "none" value, "0" seems to work.